# Mongoose update all object array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Can I update all my object array at once?

Here is my sample data

```
{
 "_id": objectId("123"),
 "username": "user",
 "address_book": [{
    "_id": objectId("456"),
    "isDefault": true,
 }, {
    "_id": objectId("678"),
    "isDefault": true,
 }, {
    "_id": objectId("321"),
    "isDefault": false,
 }] 
}
```

Im trying to update all isDefault true to false.

here is my code

```
User.updateMany(
 {
   _id: id,
   "address_book.isDefault": 1,
 },
 {
   $set: { "address_book.$.isDefault": 0 },
 },
 { multi: true }
);
```

But this code only update the first addressbook. What I need is to update all

Thank you

Comment: $ positional always update only first matching object, for all you can use arrayFilters see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Comment: Thanks its working now.